# Click Javascript button python, spynner

Tags: python, button, click, spynner

I want to click button without name using a spynner. The button looks like this:

```
<li> <a onclick="save(); return false;" href="">
<img src="/pathtoimage" width="31" height="13" alt="Save Changes"img  border="0"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Have you any idea? Please write some code.
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can call any javascript that is in the page by using(in your case):

`br = spynner.Browser()
br.runjs("save();")`

You have access to all the javascript that is accessible to the page.

Answer (score 0):

you could (2 years ago...) refer to this "button" as an image with a unique attributes.

in your example i'd use  something like:

```
browser.click('img[alt="Save Changes"]')
```